# Discord API - getting ALL of a user's roles across ALL of their guilds in fewer requests

Tags: rest, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm using Discord's API, and want to get ALL of a user's roles across all of the guilds they are in. [The documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guild-member) indicates the way to get "guild member" objects that contain info about roles for a user is through the `/users/@me/guilds/{guild.id}/member` endpoint. Each query fetches the user's roles for one guild at a time.

Is there a way to fetch ALL of a user's roles across ALL of the guilds they're in, without sending a separate request for each guild?

Comment: You would have to go over all the guilds with a `for` loop and check for the specific member and its roles in the guild, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Yeah seems like it, but I'm wondering if there's a way to batch these somehow - like if a user has 50 guilds, I want to avoid sending 50 requests if possible

Comment: I guess not, unless you maybe store all the information somehwere on the start of the bot. Even then these roles etc. can change so the get the actual and current information I see no other way around this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `for` loop to gatherin all member roles. For me I use this one in `.cogs` so I put `self` in it. You can just remove it if you not using `.cogs`

```
async def testnew(self, ctx):
    for guild in self.client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            for roles in member.roles:
```